# Get channel message history and mark views with WTelegramClient

Tags: c#, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

How can I:

- Get a public channel message history [Text, Photo, Video ...]
- Mark these messages as a viewed

With Telethon (python), we can use this method:

```
for message in client.get_messages(channel, limit=int(count)):
                result = client(functions.messages.GetMessagesViewsRequest(peer=channel,id=[message.id],increment=True))
```

I want a method like this on WTelegramClient in c#

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to get a list of messages (history) from a channel and increment the views counter for each.

> ⚠️ From the [official documentation](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id#using-the-api-id):
> If you use the Telegram API for flooding, spamming, faking subscribers, and view counters of channels, you **will be banned forever**.

The equivalent of your code with WTelegramClient would be something like this:

```cs
var msgs = await client.Messages_GetHistory(channel, limit: count);
foreach (var message in msgs.Messages)
    await client.Messages_GetMessagesViews(channel, new[] { message.ID }, true);

// possible alternate way (single API call):
await client.Messages_GetMessagesViews(channel, msgs.Messages.Select(m => m.ID).ToArray(), true);
```

See [EXAMPLES.md](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md) for detailed examples of fetching chat history.

Comment: At last! I found my answer :) I voted many times for what you provided! Thank you.